# InvalidOperationException on GetType

Tags: vb.net

I try to serialize a Class in VB using XMLSerializer.
But when I call GetType for my Class I got a InvalidOperationException error.

`Dim Playlist_serialize As New XmlSerializer(p.GetType)`

Here is my class :

```
Public Class Playlist
Private p_name As String
Private p_elements As List(Of Playlist_element)

Sub New()
    p_elements = New List(Of Playlist_element)
End Sub

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Name = p_name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        p_name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Elements() As List(Of Playlist_element)
    Get
        Elements = p_elements
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Playlist_element))
        p_elements = value
    End Set
End Property
```

---

Here is my Playlist_element :

```
Public Class Playlist_element
Private p_Name As String
Private p_Type As String
Private p_Genre As String

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Name = p_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        p_Name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Type() As String
    Get
        Type = p_Type
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        p_Type = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Genre() As String
    Get
        Genre = p_Genre
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        p_Genre = value
    End Set
End Property

Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal genre As String)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Genre = genre
    Me.Type = Type
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: that should work fine as long as `p` is an instance of `PlayList`.   Maybe show how `Playlist_element` is defined

Comment: Yes p is an instance of Playlist : `Dim p As New Playlist()`

Comment: My error is when I initialize Playlist_serialize. Yes I know I changed the name to something different but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Just pay more attention to the exception.  The Exception Assistant is helpful.  It shows you the inner exception: "Playlist_element cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."   Yup, it does not, so deserializing playlist elements cannot work, no way to get an element object created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the way `Playlist_element` is coded.  First your property getters are wrong.  They need to return the backing field:

```
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        ' this does nothing:
        'Name = p_Name
        Return p_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        p_Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Next, I would not use `Type` as a property name even if you can.  If you drill into the inner exception and view the message, it tells you that it cannot serialize `PlayList_element` because it does not have a simple constructor.  All serializers require this because they do not know how to use:

```
Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal genre As String)
    p_Name = name
    p_Genre = genre
    p_Type = type
End Sub

' add:
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

It should work fine.  I should note that as of VS2010, you can use auto-implemented properties and skip *a lot* of that code:

```
Public Class Element

    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Type() As String
    Public Property Genre() As String

    Sub New(name As String, type As String, genre As String)
        _Name = name
        _Genre = genre
        _Type = type
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

VS provides a "hidden" backing field as with `_Name`, `_Genre` etc.